# How to catch final state of seekbar?

Tags: android

```
   <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This is seekbar. I want to catch it's state when I press button..

```
      button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

             //Here i want code to catch state of seekbar!


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `getProgress()` on your seekbar.

```
    SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    ...
    sb.getProgress();
```

Answer (score 0):

get the reference of `SeekBar`

```
SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Log.e("SeekBar Progress :",sb.getProgress());
}
```